# How do you implement Table Inheritance in Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Example:

I have a base table called Pet with a `BirthDate` and `Name` columns.

I have a two more tables that derive from that table, one called PetDog table with column `NumberOfTeeth` and another called PetBird table with column `BeakColor`.

How to implement this using Kotlin Exposed? https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed

Or is there any documentation on this available?

Comment: `PetDog` table should have 3 columns (`BirthDate`, `Name`, `NumberOfTeeth`)? Or it should have 2 columns (`BirthDate`, `PetId`), where `PetId` points to some row in `Pet` table?

Answer (score 2):

What sort of database and schema do you have in mind? How does it support table inheritance? As [Михаил Нафталь](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968673/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c) already mentioned in the comment, a common approach with a relational database would be to either use one table with all columns or two tables (`pet` and `dog`, with some way to link the records in both tables to each other).

A simple example with two tables:

```
create table pet (id int auto_increment primary key, birthdate varchar(10) not null, "name" varchar(50) not null)
create table dog (id int auto_increment primary key, pet_id int not null, number_of_teeth int not null, constraint fk_dog_pet_id_id foreign key (pet_id) references pet(id) on delete restrict on update restrict)
```

Your Exposed table definition code could then look something like this:

```
object Pet : IntIdTable() {
    val birthdate = varchar("birthdate", 10)
    val name = varchar("name", 50)
}

object Dog : IntIdTable() {
    val petId = reference("pet_id", Pet).nullable()
    val numberOfTeeth = integer("number_of_teeth")
}
```

Comment: In other words, use composition over inheritance.

I would not make the Pet-reference nullable however. ;)

Comment: @TimvanderLeeuw Thanks for your comment, I agree. I've changed `pet_id` to be a non-nullable field.